Tikz graphs not aligned
I've been trying to figure the solution to no avail. I have five graphs, first four are in a 2x2 shape and last one is below them. Issue is that one of them has much higher values on y-axis which in turn creates longer number and shifts the two middle graphs to the right. How do I fix all the axes of all the graphs? I have tried using scientific format for the numbers on y axis but the shift is still happening.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % non-print
% packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{setspace} % For adjusting line spacing
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption} % Allows subfigures
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language=Python,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{gray},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=5pt,
    frame=single,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b
}
\lstdefinestyle{blackstyle}{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    frame=single,
    columns=fullflexible,
    breaklines=true,
    commentstyle=\color{black},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    identifierstyle=\color{black}
}

% Define custom WKT language
\lstdefinelanguage{WKT}{
  morekeywords={POLYGON, LINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON},
  sensitive=false,
  morecomment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]",
}
% Define WKT style
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle_wkt}{
    language=WKT,
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2
}


% Define custom colors for syntax highlighting
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{tocbibind} % Include bibliography in table of contents
\usepackage{pdfpages} % insert external pdf document
\usepackage{multicol} % use for double column writing
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
]{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{references/ref.bib} %Import the bibliography file

% Set page margins
%\geometry{
%   top=1in,    % Top margin
%   bottom=1in, % Bottom margin
%   outer=1in,  % Outer margin (opposite to binding)
%   inner=1.5in,  % Inner margin (near binding)
%} % print
\geometry{top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=3.54cm, right=2cm} % non-print


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (fig) [anchor=south west, inner sep=0] at (0,0) {
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        title={Auerberg},
                        xlabel={$\lambda$},
                        ylabel={Time (s)},
                        xmin=0, xmax=0.3,
                        ymin=50, ymax=200,
                        xtick={0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3},
                        ytick={50, 100, 150, 200},
                        legend pos=north east,
                        ymajorgrids=true,
                        grid style=dashed,
                        width=8cm,
                        height=8cm,
                        yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex}, xticklabel style={yshift=-0.5ex}
                    ]
                    \addplot[
                        color=blue,
                        mark=square,
                        ]
                        coordinates {
                        (0,172.60681986808777)(0.1,70.60920214653015)(0.2,70.32880806922913)(0.3,69.98691368103027)
                        };
                        \addlegendentry{ILP}
                    
                    \addplot[
                        color=red,
                        mark=*,
                        ]
                        coordinates {
                        (0,95.93979692459106)(0.1,68.52559900283813)(0.2,69.98267078399658)(0.3,69.79806804656982)
                        };
                        \addlegendentry{CANZAR}
                    
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \label{fig:auerberg}
            \end{subfigure} &
            \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        title={Dransdorf},
                        xlabel={$\lambda$},
                        ylabel={Time (s)},
                        xmin=0, xmax=0.3,
                        ymin=150, ymax=550,
                        xtick={0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3},
                        ytick={150, 250, 350, 450, 550},
                        legend pos=north east,
                        ymajorgrids=true,
                        grid style=dashed,
                        width=8cm,
                        height=8cm,
                        yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex}, xticklabel style={yshift=-0.5ex}
                    ]
                    \addplot[
                        color=blue,
                        mark=square,
                        ]
                        coordinates {
                        (0,532.6167280673981)(0.1,194.17212796211243)(0.2,194.9492220878601)(0.3,193.1191418170929)
                        };
                        \addlegendentry{ILP}
                    
                    \addplot[
                        color=red,
                        mark=*,
                        ]
                        coordinates {
                        (0,237.0794496536255)(0.1,194.3900182247162)(0.2,190.02095198631287)(0.3,190.37890481948853)
                        };
                        \addlegendentry{CANZAR}
                    
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \label{fig:dransdorf}
            \end{subfigure} \\
            \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        title={Endenich},
                        xlabel={$\lambda$},
                        ylabel={Time (s)},
                        xmin=0, xmax=0.3,
                        ymin=400, ymax=4000,
                        xtick={0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3},
                        ytick={400, 1000, 1500, 2000,2500,3000,3500,4000},
                        legend pos=north east,
                        ymajorgrids=true,
                        grid style=dashed,
                        width=8cm,
                        height=8cm,
                        yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex}, xticklabel style={yshift=-0.5ex}
                    ]
                    \addplot[
                        color=blue,
                        mark=square,
                        ]
                        coordinates {
                        (0,3693.8295221328735)(0.1,582.7835237979889)(0.2,566.8816678524017)(0.3,546.8623440265656)
                        };
                        \addlegendentry{ILP}
                    
                    \addplot[
                        color=red,
                        mark=*,
                        ]
                        coordinates {
                        (0,884.1521742343903)(0.1,486.0983712673187)(0.2,475.45432782173157)(0.3,476.23762369155884)
                        };
                        \addlegendentry{CANZAR}
                    
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \label{fig:endenich}
            \end{subfigure} &
            \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        title={Berkum},
                        xlabel={$\lambda$},
                        ylabel={Time (s)},
                        xmin=0, xmax=0.3,
                        ymin=200, ymax=1000,
                        xtick={0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3},
                        ytick={200, 400, 600, 800,1000},
                        legend pos=north east,
                        ymajorgrids=true,
                        grid style=dashed,
                        width=8cm,
                        height=8cm,
                        yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex}, xticklabel style={yshift=-0.5ex}
                    ]
                    \addplot[
                        color=blue,
                        mark=square,
                        ]
                        coordinates {
                        (0,912.9678349494934)(0.1,250.23137307167053)(0.2,251.945170879364)(0.3,240.4560980796814)
                        };
                        \addlegendentry{ILP}
                    
                    \addplot[
                        color=red,
                        mark=*,
                        ]
                        coordinates {
                        (0,413.33777713775635)(0.1,237.5415301322937)(0.2,238.04754495620728)(0.3,234.12637782096863)
                        };
                        \addlegendentry{CANZAR}
                    
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \label{fig:berkum}
            \end{subfigure} \\
            \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        title={Werthhoven},
                        xlabel={$\lambda$},
                        ylabel={Time ()},
                        xmin=0, xmax=0.3,
                        ymin=0, ymax=100,
                        xtick={0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3},
                        ytick={0, 25, 50, 100},
                        legend pos=north east,
                        ymajorgrids=true,
                        grid style=dashed,
                        width=8cm,
                        height=8cm,
                        ticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2, yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex}, xticklabel style={yshift=-0.5ex}}
                    ]
                    \addplot[
                        color=blue,
                        mark=square,
                        ]
                        coordinates {
                        (0,90.53524494171143)(0.1,36.438645124435425)(0.2,36.65896439552307)(0.3,37.221980810165405)
                        };
                        \addlegendentry{ILP}
                    
                    \addplot[
                        color=red,
                        mark=*,
                        ]
                        coordinates {
                        (0,44.19272208213806)(0.1,37.984986782073975)(0.2,37.373470306396484)(0.3,36.657711029052734)
                        };
                        \addlegendentry{CANZAR}
                    
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \label{fig:werthhoven}
            \end{subfigure} &
        \end{tabular}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{Comparison of ILP and CANZAR over different datasets}
    \label{fig:comparison}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Did you test the code as shown in your question to ensure that it has all packages etc it needs?

If I guess the missing package, I still don't get the result as shown in your image.

I thought these are the ones needed. This is part of a much larger document with many packages, I will add them in the original question in a second.

Instead of guessing I suggest to comment out all packages, compile, and uncomment the really missing ones. The compiler is your friend …

Thanks for the idea; with the edited code above, issue is replicated in a standalone document.

See if the following MWE givers what you after. In it I

reduce preamble to loading only to your problem relevant packages (geometry, pgfplots (version 1.18), subcaption)
from diagram code remove tabular code, it is not needed, and adjustbox (instead it I rather define smaller diagrams width)
define common axis style for all diagrams, so locally are defined only title, ymin, ymax
in common styles I add ylabel style={yshift=-1em}, and change yticklabel style to yticklabel style={text width=3.3em, align=right},
commented are all labels in subfigure environments. If you not have captions in them, labels has no sense (gives wrong reference)

So, my MWE, which solve your problem (if I understood it correctly) is:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin={3.54cm, 2cm}, vmargin=2.54cm, 
          showframe} 
%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{subcaption} % Allows subfigures


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\pgfplotsset{  
    width=70mm,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed, 
    xmin=0, xmax=0.3,         
    xtick={0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3},
    xlabel={$\lambda$},
    ylabel={Time (s)},
    ylabel style={yshift=-1em},  % <---
    yticklabel style={text width=2.9em, align=right},  % <---
            }                
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{axis}[
    title={Auerberg},
    ymin=50, ymax=200,
    ytick={50, 100, 150, 200},
            ]
\addplot[
        color=blue,
        mark=square,
        ]   coordinates {(0,172.60681986808777) (0.1,70.60920214653015) 
                        (0.2,70.32880806922913) (0.3,69.98691368103027)};
        \addlegendentry{ILP}
                    
\addplot[
        color=red,
        mark=*,
        ]   coordinates {(0,95.93979692459106)  (0.1,68.52559900283813) 
                         (0.2,69.98267078399658) (0.3,69.79806804656982)};
                        \addlegendentry{CANZAR}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%    \label{fig:auerberg}
    \end{subfigure} 
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Dransdorf},
    xlabel={$\lambda$},
    ymin=150, ymax=550,
    ytick={150, 250, 350, 450, 550},    
            ]
\addplot[
        color=blue,
        mark=square,
        ] coordinates  {(0,532.6167280673981) (0.1,194.17212796211243)
                        (0.2,194.9492220878601) (0.3,193.1191418170929)};
                        \addlegendentry{ILP}
\addplot[
        color=red,
        mark=*,
        ] coordinates  {(0,237.0794496536255) (0.1,194.3900182247162)
                        (0.2,190.02095198631287) (0.3,190.37890481948853)
                        };
        \addlegendentry{CANZAR}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%\label{fig:dransdorf}
    \end{subfigure}
            
\medskip            
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{axis}[
    title={Endenich},
    ytick={400, 1000, 1500, 2000,2500,3000,3500,4000},
            ]
\addplot[
        color=blue,
        mark=square,
        ] coordinates {(0,3693.8295221328735) (0.1,582.7835237979889)
                       (0.2,566.8816678524017) (0.3,546.8623440265656)};
        \addlegendentry{ILP}
\addplot[
        color=red,
        mark=*,
        ] coordinates {(0,884.1521742343903) (0.1,486.0983712673187)
                       (0.2,475.45432782173157) (0.3,476.23762369155884)};
        \addlegendentry{CANZAR}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%\label{fig:endenich}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Berkum},
    ymin=200, ymax=1000,
    ytick={200, 400, 600, 800,1000},
            ]
\addplot[
        color=blue,
        mark=square,
        ] coordinates {(0,912.9678349494934) (0.1,250.23137307167053)
                       (0.2,251.945170879364) (0.3,240.4560980796814)};
                        \addlegendentry{ILP}
\addplot[
        color=red,
        mark=*,
        ] coordinates { (0,413.33777713775635) (0.1,237.5415301322937)
                        (0.2,238.04754495620728) (0.3,234.12637782096863)};
        \addlegendentry{CANZAR}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%\label{fig:berkum}
    \end{subfigure} 
    
\medskip    
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Werthhoven},
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    ytick={0, 25, 50, 100},
            ]
\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ] coordinates { (0,90.53524494171143) (0.1,36.438645124435425)
                    (0.2,36.65896439552307) (0.3,37.221980810165405)};
    \addlegendentry{ILP}
    \addplot[
            color=red,
            mark=*,
            ] coordinates { (0,44.19272208213806) (0.1,37.984986782073975)
                            (0.2,37.373470306396484) (0.3,36.657711029052734)};
    \addlegendentry{CANZAR}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%\label{fig:werthhoven}
    \end{subfigure}

\caption{Comparison of ILP and CANZAR over different datasets}
\label{fig:comparison}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}

which gives

In the case, that you like to have last image aligned at left border, remove \centering after \begin{figure}

Yes, this definitely solves the issue. Thank you!

@mm6643, you are welcome!
